# compare two arrays in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
[
  {
    "receiverWorkout": {
      "_id": "5b4f3920c805e1299b90716c",
      "name": "nmbnmbnmnbm",
      "exercises": [
        {
          "_id": "5b4f3920c805e1299b90716f",
          "reps": 0,
          "weights": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5b4c3920c805e1299b90716f",
          "reps": 4,
          "weights": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "senderWorkout": {
      "_id": "5b4f11f16cf99524f21d2287",
      "name": "nmbnmbnmnbm",
      "exercises": [
        {
          "_id": "5b4f11f16cf99524f21d2288",
          "reps": 12,
          "weights": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5b4f7920c805e1299b90716f",
          "reps": 8,
          "weights": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I need to compare both the exercises array and add new field called `won` to only `senderWorkout` ... Winning will be calculated on the `reps` field... And same index exercises will be matched i.e. first with first exercise and second with second exercise...

So my expected output will be

```
[
  {
    "receiverWorkout": {
      "_id": "5b4f3920c805e1299b90716c",
      "name": "nmbnmbnmnbm",
      "exercises": [
        {
          "_id": "5b4f3920c805e1299b90716f",
          "reps": 0,
          "weights": 0
        },
        {
          "_id": "5b4c3920c805e1299b90716f",
          "reps": 4,
          "weights": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "senderWorkout": {
      "_id": "5b4f11f16cf99524f21d2287",
      "name": "nmbnmbnmnbm",
      "exercises": [
        {
          "_id": "5b4f11f16cf99524f21d2288",
          "reps": 12,
          "weights": 0,
          "result": "won"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5b4f7920c805e1299b90716f",
          "reps": 2,
          "weights": 0,
          "result": "lost"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4 aggregation.

[`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) to iterate over `senderWorkout` exercises and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to keep the exercise fields along with extra field to compare the array elements and output the boolean field.

[`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) expression with index ( from `$range` (ix) ) to output the sender and receiver element.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to update only senderWorkout exercise while keeping all the existing fields.

```
db.colname.aggregate({
  "$addFields":{
    "senderWorkout.exercises":{
      "$map":{
        "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$senderWorkout.exercises"}]},
        "as":"ix",
        "in":{
          "$let":{
            "vars":{
              "rec":{"$arrayElemAt":["$receiverWorkout.exercises","$$ix"]},
              "sen":{"$arrayElemAt":["$senderWorkout.exercises","$$ix"]}
            },
            "in":{
              "_id":"$$sen._id",
              "reps":"$$sen.reps",
              "weights":"$$sen.weights",
              "won":{"$gt":["$$sen.reps","$$rec.reps"]}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks!!! that's exactly what I want... Perfect man you are awesome... Can you please explain how `$range` and `$let` works here?

Comment: Yw. `$range` will iterate the sender array and `$let` to output the sender and receiver array element at the index followed by comparison to produce win field.